# Why does stringify() only return 1st level of object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, stringify

We're building a dynamic JSON payload according to a simple template format that instructs how many levels our payload should produce, e.g. "level1.level2" > will produce:

```
{
  "level1": [
     {
       "level2": [
           {
              "someData": "willGoHere",
           },
           {
              "someOtherData": "willAlsoGoHere"
           }
       ]
     }
  ]
}
```

Obviously we're working with a different naming structure, e.g: "client.ipcEvent.level3" and in some cases we're testing 4 levels. We're doing something wrong ~ we're able to build our javascript object but unable to use stringify() to create a full *result* because for some strange reason stringify() against our object only returns the 1st level's data:

```
{ "level1": [] }
```

[image: Valid XHTML].

I've tried changing the way in which our object is loaded with values but it all comes back to stringify() 'dropping' off array values that don't have accompanying attribute/property values at the same level.

Comment: Can you include the code where you make a call to stringify? When I try it with the data you provide, I get the full result

Comment: @OliverRadini - Yeah, the example structure doesn't replicate it (and should), but you can tell from the screenshot what's going on.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah that makes sense - I think I've developed screenshot blindness!

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that your `client` is an *array*, but you've put properties on it that aren't array entries (which you can do because arrays are objects):

[image]

`JSON.stringify` only includes the array entries of an array, not its other properties:

```js
const a = [];
a.nonEntryProperty = "foo";
a[0] = "bar";
console.log(JSON.stringify(a)); // ["bar"]
```

To ensure data is serialized to JSON correctly, include object-like properties in objects, and array entries in arrays:

```js
const structure = {
  info: {
    nonEntryProperty: "foo"
  },
  array: ["bar"]
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(structure, null, 4));
```

Comment: Hi TJ, is there a work around? Do i "unpack" the json from the inside - out?

Comment: Don't add properties to array objects, rather make an object containing an array-property like `{"bar":"foo","contents":[1,4,6]}`

Comment: @GregRowles - Meant to say in the answer (doh!): Use objects for object stuff, arrays for array stuff. I've updated it, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

OK, solved; we were creating arrays when it should have been objects, and vice-versa; sorry for the vague question but thank you TJ and Sebastian. Based on the specification of "level1.level2" the solution was to create object {} for "level1" and array [] for the last item "level2"...